# Determining dictionary value in python based on current system time

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary created with key as time in `%H:%M:%S` and value for it .

```
dict = {
 '06:00:01': '0x95', '06:10:01': '0x97', 
 '06:20:01': '0x98', '06:30:01': '0x99',
 '06:40:01': '0x101', '06:50:01': '0x102',
 '07:00:01': '0x104', '07:10:01': '0x105',
 '07:20:01': '0x106', '07:30:01': '0x107',
 '07:40:01': '0x109', '07:50:01': '0x110',
 '08:00:01': '0x111', '08:10:01': '0x112',
 '08:20:01': '0x113', '08:30:01': '0x114',
 '08:40:01': '0x115', '08:50:01': '0x116',
 '09:00:01': '0x117', '09:10:01': '0x118',
 '09:20:01': '0x119', '09:30:01': '0x119',
 '09:40:01': '0x120', '09:50:01': '0x121',
 '10:00:01': '0x122', '10:10:01': '0x122',
 '10:20:01': '0x123', '10:30:01': '0x124',
 '10:40:01': '0x124', '10:50:01': '0x125',
 '11:00:01': '0x125', '11:10:01': '0x126',
 '11:20:01': '0x126', '11:30:01': '0x126',
 '11:40:01': '0x127', '11:50:01': '0x127',
 '12:00:01': '0x127', '12:10:01': '0x128',
 '12:20:01': '0x128'
}
```

I am trying to think of logic which will return the dictionary value based on current system time. If current system time is in range of two key values of dictionary it should return value of lower key in python

Comment: In case you don't see my edits - you're overwriting a default name for dictionary object. In my program I renamed it to `date_dict`.

Comment: I didn't realize that . Thanks for correcting me! I will be testing out your answer soon .

Comment: I had it on the back of my mind to tell you, and then completely forgot about it until next day. Let me know how's it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes that you are not using the am/pm format:

```
from datetime import datetime

cur_time = datetime.now().time()
print cur_time

keys = sorted(date_dict.keys())
times = [datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S") for i in keys]

out = False
for idx, t in enumerate(times):
    if cur_time >= t.time():
        t1 = times[min(idx+1, len(times)-1)].time()
        if cur_time <= t1:
            out = date_dict[str(t.time())]
print out
```

I switched the default name for a dictionary object `dict` to `date_dict` - that's exactly the dictionary from your question. Using the default names overwrites them, so it shouldn't be done.

`cur_time` is the current time, printed for convenience. `keys` is a list of sorted dictionary keys that are then turned into a list `times` of `datetime` objects. This can be done in one line but seams more readable this way.

The for loop uses `enumerate` to access both the `datetime` objects and their indices `idx`. If the current time is larger or equal to the `datetime` objects time, the code checks if it is also smaller or equal to the next object in the list. If that is the case, the current time fits in that range and the lower value of the lower key (`t.time()`) is assigned to `out`. If it's not in the dictionary range at all, the value will be remain the default 'False'.

The part `times[min(idx+1, len(times)-1)]` prevents the index to go out of range for values that are larger than `'12:20:01'`.

You can easily test this program by using `timedelta` and generating various times, here different by hours:

```
from datetime import timedelta

cur_time = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=8)).time()
```